# Illustrator pen tool problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

Please help me, i am a beginner and started to watch the Illustrator tutorials on their website. When they use the Pen tool they can draw strait line, but mine starts from the middle, and draw curves, etc.

[image]

[image: .]

Comment: are you clicking, holding and moving, or are you clicking, releasing and moving? The results will be different from one action to the other.

Comment: You may also want to check out [The Bezier Game](https://bezier.method.ac/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's pretty easy:

To continue a curved line with a straight one you simply need to press Alt and click on the anchor point (while drawing with the pen tool) from where you would like to start drawing straight. This will remove the curved path handle from that point on.

Check it out:

[image]

> To continue with straight lines further on simply "click and release"
>   instead of "click, drag and release" (like you did for those curved
>   paths).